# Exception in running Sparks example code

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to execute the code at

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py

But I am getting an exception

An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

I am not able to figure out what could be the reason for this. I have spark 1.2 build for hadoop 2.4. Will be great if someone can throw some light on this

Comment: That probably means you have the wrong version of Java jar file. The signature of a method in a class is now now different than what's expected. I don't know the Python API, but make sure you're using compatible versions of the Spark code built for your version of Hadoop and Cassandra.

Comment: I am using Spark 1.2 built for hadoop 2.4 and cassandra 2.1.2. Both of them are at their latest version. The jar file that I am using is at SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar . Any idea which combinations of spark and cassandra would work together?

Comment: @DeanWampler can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace and can you tell exactly where it blew up in that code? It's probably not the Cassandra connection, based on the this error message, but it's hard to tell. Since I don't know the Python API nor the connectors to Cassandra, you should ask on spark-users, too.